# ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have read many messages dealing with this issue. But nothing, so far, resulted in the solution.
More details:
This is ASP.NET Web Forms (not MVC) project in VS 2012.
This error occurs on processing of Login.aspx.
The problem only happens when I Debug with Internet Explorer. When I debug with Chrome, the scripts load fine.
I created another - for testing - ASP.NET Web Forms solution and it works. So I presume that nothing in the framework is corrupted.

Here is the offending code:

```
<script src="/bundles/MsAjaxJs?v=_Onj24X0Yu7cK2nh78YBmVwMlQTGcakS5HZSOI_a6SM1" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to   
load.');
//]]>
```

Comment: Do you have code that we can look at?

Comment: @msm8bball  I added the code to my initial post.

Comment: That code is generated by ASP.NET. What version of IE are you using ?

Comment: @sh1rts I have IE 9 installed on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

OK - so it's not the IE11 issue :)

This doesn't happen on any other page using IE; but are any of your other pages using ASP.NET Ajax ?

Can you try using the network trace tool in IE (Network tab of the debug tools) to see what responses the browser is getting when requesting resources for login.aspx ?

Also can you check your compatibility mode settings in IE - make sure it's IE9 document standards.

If none of this is any good, can you post the code for login.aspx ?

*Edited*

You didn't mention Forms Auth was being used. Try adding an exception `<location>` path  to web.config for the path to the script resources, for example: -

```
  <location path="admin/css" allowOverride="true">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: To: sh1rts.  The Network tab of the debug gets stuck on line /bundles/MsAjaxJs?v=...The problem started when I installed DOTLESS package. So what I will do is trace back - remove DOTLESS from web.config and see it makes the differnce.
Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome Hidalgo. Be interested to see the results of your work, maybe there is potentially some incompatibility between Dotless and ASP.NET Ajax ?

Comment: To: sh1rts (the @ does not work).  I found that if I change my project from Form Authentication to Anonymous Authentication, I don't get the error and everything works. Therefore, the problem I believe is that before the site is authenticated, "something" prevents the ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework fails to load.  But I don't know what to change.

Comment: To: sh1rts. Since the error (my initial message) points to problem loading MSAjax scripts, shouldn't the path in the location (code you posted) point to these script files?  The actual path in my project is:
Scripts/WebForms/MSAjax.  Therefore, do you think that the following should be better in path?
    path = "scripts/WebForms/MSAjax"

Comment: Hi - yes that's correct; the path in my example was from one of my projects. You should add <location> tags with your paths. Sorry for the confusion !

Comment: Thank you, Sh1rts. Still no solution but I believe the problem could have something to do with IE. I will be testing on another computer next week.
Happy Holidays!

Comment: You're welcome friend :) I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. Let me know how you go !